# What are advantages/disadvantages of using Selenium for Java vs .NET applications?

Tags: c#, java, .net, selenium

I'm a test lead in a new project where we're starting with re-writing from scratch some web application which is about 12 years old.
We have quite a free hand with defining processes and technologies. 
My goal is to have automated functional (for regression) tests with Selenium 2 (in python) connected with some Continuous Integration server.

Currently we're considering 2 technologies Java vs .NET (C#)

And my rather general question is: are there any advantages/disadvantages of using selenium 2 for Java vs .NET applications?

From my (tester) perspective I don't think that this would have a significant impact on my automation tests because we'll be creating them from user perspective but maybe I'm wrong and that's why I'm asking it in this place.

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Selenium primarily tests rendered code so it arguably makes little or no difference what language or framework you ae testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter what language the application is written in.  Selenium tests through the browser, and it can't tell the difference between a Java web app and one in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently testing Java-based web application and here are moreover general tips on how the developement should build them:

- Every Web Element should have unique and unchangeable ID. This will assure you, that you can run your selenium scripts over and over again.
- The application should have form based authentification
- For better writing tests, the app should show "working" picture/message whenewer its doing something

Its more like about being good web developer in general than used technology. Selenium is "just clicking" the final product - HTML page generated by the programming language.

BTW, here on StackOverflow, most people use WebDriver and JUnit (Java). Think about it before writing the scripts. Because if you have any python - related issue, I cannot help :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Pavel. As for python vs java the thing is that I'm more advanced in python and rest of the team will have to learn any language from the beginning, so I thought that it would be more efficient for them to start with python rather than java.