# Why Java for Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Why is Selenium written in Java famous over other languages it support? I know that,

- We have good support for Selenium with Java
- Majority of Users use Java in today's market
- Java is a platform independent language.

I would like to know a clear comparison of differences in using Selenium with Java VS Selenium with scripting languages like Python or Ruby

Any reference to articles, presentation, discussions, forums, anything else is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960897/selenium-webdriver-with-java-vs-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379497/what-are-advantages-disadvantages-of-using-selenium-for-java-vs-net-application

Comment: You also must look at it from another point of view. It is not necessarily it is "better" than another, but certainly in some countries, it is taught at university and schools simply because it's free (although C# is becoming more common place). People simply "learnt" Java first. Java is an incredibly easy language.